# Pythons requests library removing appending question mark from URL

Tags: python, python-requests

### Goal

Make request to `http://example.com/page?` using `requests.get()`

### Problem

The question mark ("?") is automatically stripped from the request if it is the last character in the URL (eg. `http://example.com/page?1` and `http://example.com/page?!` work, `http://example.com/page?` does *not*)

### Sample code

```py
import requests

endpoint = "http://example.com/page?"
r = requests.get(endpoint)

print(r.url) # -> "http://example.com/page"
assert r.url == endpoint # Raises AssertionError
```

### Question

Without modifying the library, is it possible to reach the intended endpoint? Both intended solutions (if such exist) and workarounds are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason to justify this need? Cause the `?` flag is used in URLs to separate the 'route' from the parameters, such as `https://www.google.com/search?q=stack`. So if no params are passed in the request, it makes sense to ignore a trailing `?`

Comment: Yes, it is needed for communicating with an old internal API. Previously a javascript library was used for making the request, but I'm exploring if the program could be ported to python 3.

Comment: Is it being redirected? What's the status code?

Comment: @Jim The server returns a 404 error, however the question about the limits of the requests library interest me personally

Comment: Does the `?` at the end really make a difference? As far as the endpoint being requested from the server, the `?` is doing nothing. This is not a _limit_ of the `requests` library. `requests` uses something to parse the URL with, and since the `?` means nothing in this instance, it is removed.

Comment: You're right, the `?` at the end should not make a difference. APIs that require such an unusual combination are arguably poorly configured, and likely have other problems as well. 

However, that is not my question. I merely wonder if it possible to do at all with the requests library.

Comment: Would an URL such as `http://example.com/?=` suffice? This can be done by passing `params` to `requests.get`.
Example: `r = requests.get("http://www.google.com", params={'': ''})` renders `r.url` as `http://www.google.com/?=`

Comment: To the best of my knowledge this is not possible with the `requests` module exactly the way you want it. The closest urls you could try are `http://example.com/page?=` and `http://example.com/page??`. It is possible with `urllib.request`, however.

Comment: Exactly what you request, I believe it is not possible. There has been a discussion on a (now) closed issue on `requests` codebase and someone did propose a solution that would allow this to be done easily (link to comment [here](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2651#issuecomment-497667535)), but it seems it was left out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is *not* possible with the `requests` library. URLs passed into `requests` are parsed by `urllib3.util.url.parse_url()` into separate parts:

```
scheme
auth
host
port
path
query
fragment
```

The logic for getting the `query` part of a URL assumes that the querystring starts after `?`, but since there is nothing after the question mark, it gives a blank `query`. The URL is then reconstructed as a string when you print `r.url`. That is why the URL does not have the trailing question mark.

I found that the behavior you are looking for is possible with `urllib.request`, though. Here's an example:

```py
import urllib.request, urllib.error

try:
    response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://example.com/page?") 
    print(response.url)  # -> http://example.com/page?
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    print(e.url)  # -> http://example.com/page?
    print(e.code) # -> 404
```

I have surrounded the request in a `try/except` because if the page you are trying to get gives a 404, `urllib` will raise an error, where `requests` will simply put up with it.

Answer (score 0):

not an answer but more on requests behaviour

I can give you `http://example.com/page?=` with :

```
import requests


endpoint = "http://example.com/page"
r = requests.get(endpoint, params = {'':''})

# r = requests.get(endpoint)

print(r.url) # -> "http://example.com/page"

assert r.url == endpoint+'?=' # Raises AssertionError
```